# Does multiplication by juxtaposition have the same precedence as normal multiplication in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In saying multiplication by juxtaposition in algebra, I mean writing the numbers and letters side by side when multiplying them. So, for instance, rather than writing $4 \times x^2$, you write $4x^2$, which is obviously more precise. You can also write $4 \cdot x^2$.

Now let's say we want to divide $4x^2$ by $2x$. $4x^2 \div 2x$, using the simple rules of exponents, equals $2x$, which we know is true because $2x \cdot 2x$ equals $4x^2$.

However, according to the order of operations, multiplication and division goes from left to right. Therefore, $4x^2 \div 2x$ would be $4 \cdot x^2 \div 2 \cdot x$, which then becomes $4x^2 \div 2 \cdot x$, which equals $2x^3$. Does this mean writing the letters side by side holds precedence over writing them using the traditional notation for multiplication?

Comment: The conclusions are simply that (a) you should use parentheses whenever potential ambiguity results, and (b) writing expressions with fractions in one line is terrible practice.

Comment: I disagree with (b). I would certainly write $4x^2/2x$ and expect it to be reliably interpreted as $4x^2/(2x)$. So yes (to the OP), one of the evolved uses of the multiplication-by-juxtaposition notation is to indicate a more tightly bound precedence. But here's the most important thing I can say: "order of operations" is not a mathematical truth that is meant to override actual usage; rather, it is a hopefully helpful but imperfect way of capturing actual usage.